# Can not curl docker swarm from remote host

Tags: curl, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm

I'm trying to test how to interact with docker swarm using docker API. I have an ec2 instance in AWS running docker. I need to connect to it from my local machine using curl then initialize the swarm and get the join tokens after to use it to connect 2 other ec2 instances to the swarm. I need to do all of that using curl only.

I created the swarm manually by ssh'ing to the instance and running:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.0.0.2
```

and then I tried running this curl command:

```
curl 10.0.0.2:2377/swarm
curl 10.0.0.2:2377/info
```

and I get an empty line. If I try changing the port to 2376 I get connection refused error.

What am I missing?

running netstat -tuplen, found the following result:

[image]

Comment: Add -i to curl and show it. `curl -i .......`

Comment: same result nothing gets returned back

Comment: Seems like an obvious question, but what service are you running on the Swarm? Did you expose ports when you launched it?

Comment: @ManoMarks thanks for your comment! I dont have any services running now and I need to connect to the swarm manager itself not the services. correct if I'm wrong but I don't think the manager's port needs an extra setup to be exposed right?

Comment: Sorry I missed the part where you wrote API. You're trying to use the remote api. So by default it requires you to connect using https, which requires a certificate. More info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/ did you start in secure mode?

Comment: can I use username/password for authentication instead of certificates?

Comment: You might be able to do it with an authorization plugin. But there's work there, it's designed to be secure by default. You can turn off https authentication. For more info on auth plugins, here's a recent blog post by a Docker Captain: http://blog.loof.fr/2017/07/writing-docker-authorization-plugin.html?spref=tw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull the answer out of the comments: By default accessing the remote API has to be done with [https authentication](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/). You can turn that off but this isn't recommended for production apps. There may be a way to write an authorization plugin that will allow other forms of authentication access.